# Join operation on attributes from arrow structs

Tags: python, database, apache-arrow

Assume I have a json file named 'my_data.json' as below.

```
{"a": [1, 2], "b": {"c": true, "d": "1991-02-03"}}
{"a": [3, 4, 5], "b": {"c": false, "d": "2019-04-01"}}
```

If I need to do a join operation based on attribute d, can I do it directly from arrow structs? ( or are there any efficient alternatives?)
Also how nested attributes in json format are mapped into buffers once converted in arrow format?

```
>>> table = json.read_json("my_data.json")
>>> table
pyarrow.Table
a: list<item: int64>
  child 0, item: int64
b: struct<c: bool, d: timestamp[s]>
  child 0, c: bool
  child 1, d: timestamp[s]
>>> table.to_pandas()
           a                                       b
0     [1, 2]   {'c': True, 'd': 1991-02-03 00:00:00}
1  [3, 4, 5]  {'c': False, 'd': 2019-04-01 00:00:00}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `flatten` the table before converting it to pandas: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.Table.html#pyarrow.Table.flatten

```
>>> table.flatten().to_pandas()
           a    b.c        b.d
0     [1, 2]   True 1991-02-03
1  [3, 4, 5]  False 2019-04-01
```

Then you can join on column `b.d` or `b.c`